# configure culture configuration in MVC3 application

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, windows

I deployed a MVC3 Application that works well in development environment, that's because the date format in the develop machine it's `dd/mm/yyyy`. But When The application was deploy in the server starts to getting errors in the server side for not valid Dates, because in the server the format of date it's `mm/dd/yyyy`. Now my question it's Do i need to configure the server?? or only the IIS 7.0 for this specific culture??. Whatever the answer was please let me know how can I do this. I'm working in a windows server 2008 R2 and iis 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only challenge for cultures is for date formats that will work on any server, do yourself a favor and don't use culture-specific date formats.  Use a culture-neutral date format:

yyyy-MM-dd is the same everywhere.

If you really want to localize your app to a specific culture, there is a `<globalization>` element in web.config where you can specify the culture.

Internationalization is a vast topic.  Entire books have been written about it.  There may be multiple culture issues to solve.  You're asking about the server culture, but what about the clients that connect?  If you really want to accommodate cultures, you would get the client culture from Accept-Languages part of the HTTP Header.

**globalization element in web.config**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

**Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3, JavaScript and jQuery**
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

**jQuery Globalization Plugin from Microsoft**
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

**.NET Internationalization: The Developer's Guide to Building Global Windows and Web Applications**
[http://www.amazon.com/NET-Internationalization-Developers-Building-Applications/dp/0321341384](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321341384)